# Is there any drawback of --devmode when installing a snap package?

Tags: libreoffice, snap

According to [How to Install LibreOffice 5.3 on Ubuntu (With One Command)](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2017/02/install-libreoffice-5-3-ubuntu-snap), LibreOffice 5.3 is available as a snap package.

`sudo snap install libreoffice`

will be about a 300MB download but

`sudo snap install libreoffice --devmode`

(357.43 MB) will allow better integration because the application will run "unconfined".

So, if I use --devmode, will the application:

- use my choice of gtk theme, cursor and fonts ?
- read files in ~/Documents and save to the same location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> use my choice of gtk theme, cursor and fonts ?

Probably not, that's still a work-in-progress, see [here](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/use-the-system-gtk-theme/496).

> read files in ~/Documents and save to the same location?

That should now be possible with the normal `strict` snap :)